# Read csv to object of object for d3 [datamaps]

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm using datamaps and would like to be able to read the data from a csv file.

The data format that datamaps is expecting is the following:

```
var loadeddata = {
    "JPN":{Rate:17.5,fillKey:"firstCat"},
    "DNK":{Rate:16.6,fillKey:"secondCat"}
    };
```

I would like to read a csv file of the following structure and transform it into the format that datamaps is expecting:

```
ISO, Rate, fillKey
JPN, 17.5, firstCat
DNK, 16.6, secondCat
```

My 'best attempt' was using the following code:

```
var csvloadeddata;

d3.csv("simpledata.csv", function (error, csv) {
  if (error) return console.log("there was an error loading the csv: " + error);
  console.log("there are " + csv.length + " elements in my csv set");

  var nestFunction = d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.ISO;});

  csvloadeddata = nestFunction.entries(
                      csv.map(function(d){ 
                                     d.Rate = +d.Rate;  
                                     d.fillKey = d.fillKey;  
                                     return d;  
                                 })
                    ); 
  console.log("there are " + csvloadeddata.length + " elements in my data");
});
```

But this code generates a variable 'csvloadeddata' that looks like this:

```
var csvloadeddata =  [
      {"key": "JPN", "values": { 0: {Rate:17.5, fillKey:"firstCat"}} },
      {"key": "DNK",  values : { 1: {Rate:16.6,fillKey:"secondCat"}} }
    ];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Can you post your solution as an answer (and accept it once the system lets you) so this shows up as an answered question?

Comment: Thanks for telling me! Just did this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. If somebody is interested – this is what I ended up using:

```
<script>  
d3.csv("simpledata.csv", function(error, csvdata1) {

    globalcsvdata1 = csvdata1;

    for (var i=0;i<csvdata1.length;i++)
        { 
                globalcsvdata1[ globalcsvdata1[i].ISO] = globalcsvdata1[i] ;
                //console.log(globalcsvdata1[i]);
                delete  globalcsvdata1[i].ISO;
                delete  globalcsvdata1[i] ;
            }
myMap.updateChoropleth(globalcsvdata1);

}

);



var myMap = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('map'),
    scope: 'world',
    geographyConfig: {
        popupOnHover: true,
        highlightOnHover: false
    },
    fills: {
        'AA': '#1f77b4',
        'BB': '#9467bd',
        defaultFill: 'grey'
    }


});



     </script>
</body>
```

The csv has the following structure:

```
ISO,fillKey
RUS,AA
USA,BB
```

Here is a working example: http://www.explainingprogress.com/wp-content/uploads/datamaps/uploaded_gdpPerCapita2011_PWTrgdpe/gdpPerCapita2011_PWTrgdpe.html